# Why does it look as if my object is destroyed twice?

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

I read some things about pointers in C++ and that one should not create everything as pointer. To understand this more and see how it works I wrote a little Programm:

A `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Master.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Master master = Master("master");

    master.printSlaves();

    return 0;
}
```

A `Master.h`

```
class Master
{
public:
    Master(std::string name);

    ~Master();

    void printSlaves()
    {
        _slave1.printName();
        _slave2->printName();
    }

private:
    Slave   _slave1;
    Slave   *_slave2;

    std::string _name;
};
```

and a `Master.cpp`

```
#include "Master.h"

Master::Master(std::string name)
{
    std::cout << "Master() entered." << std::endl;
    _name = name;

    _slave2 = new Slave("slave2");
    _slave1 = Slave("slave1");

    std::cout << "\t" << _name << " created." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Master() exited." << std::endl;

}

Master::~Master()
{
    std::cout << "\t" << _name << " destroyed." << std::endl;
}
```

and `Slave.h`

```
class Slave
{
public:
    Slave()
    {

    }

    Slave(std::string name);

    void printName()
    {
        std::cout << "my name is " << _name << std::endl;
    }

    ~Slave();

private:
    std::string _name;
};
```

and `Slave.cpp`

```
#include "Slave.h"

Slave::Slave(std::string name)
{
    std::cout << "Slave() entered." << std::endl;

    _name = name;

    std::cout << "\t" << _name << " created." << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Slave() exited." << std::endl;


}

Slave::~Slave()
{
    std::cout << "\t" << _name << " destroyed." << std::endl;
}
```

I expected as output :

`Master() entered.
Slave() entered.
    slave2 created.
Slave() exited.
Slave() entered.
    slave1 created.
Slave() exited.
    master created.
Master() exited.
my name is slave1
my name is slave2
    master destroyed.
    slave1 destroyed.`

but I got

`Master() entered.
Slave() entered.
    slave2 created.
Slave() exited.
Slave() entered.
    slave1 created.
Slave() exited.
    **slave1 destroyed.**
    master created.
Master() exited.
my name is slave1
my name is slave2
    master destroyed.
    **slave1 destroyed.**`

So apparently my `slave1` is destroyed twice. I don't understand why this is the case and why this is even possible.

Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: Just to say, this is a very well put question with a good example.

Comment: It's because slavery is illegal.

Comment: Actually it's a lot more verbose than it needs to be.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, do you talk about my code or my question? The code is kind of inflated. That's because I was lazy

Comment: @user2699453: Yes, that's the problem. Please do not be lazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in the line

```
_slave1 = Slave("slave1");
```

A temporary slave is created for the part `Slave("slave1");`, and then assigned to `_slave1`. After the assignment, the temporary `Slave` object is destroyed.

If you write your code like

```
Master::Master(std::string name):_slave1("slave1")
{
 //other code
}
```

then it will be created and destroyed only once.

Comment: just to mention, if you enable optimizations the compiler is allowed to elide(I hope this word is right eh) copy constructor and directly init _slave1 as if it was directly constructed. More read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision

Comment: @TheOne, here `assignment` operator is used, not `copy constructor`. To permit *copy elision*, you have to write _slave1(Slave("slave1"));

Comment: for `_slave2` you would need `_slave2(new Slave("slave2"))`. also you really should `delete` `_slave2` in `Master`'s destructor.

Comment: @user2699453, yes, like `Master::Master(std::string name):_slave1("slave1"), _slave2(new Slave("slave2"))`

Comment: Bind it by reference and the temporary object will also remain as long as the reference is alive.

Comment: @ctor, I know, but my goal was to test when the two `Slaves` are deleted, since I got a memory leak in a bigger project

Comment: @user2699453: Try `const Slave &_slave1 = Slave1("slave1");`.

Comment: @user2699453: No worries, was just some advice in case you didn't know. :)

Comment: @RakibulHasan, could you give me a link or a phrase to search for, so I can learn more about this issue?

Comment: @user2699453, the rule is simple, an object is destroyed when goes out of scope, whether you explicitly create it, or they come as temporary. Consider making the objects *non-copyable/assignable* by making `copy-constructor` and `assignemnt-operator` private if appropriate. For preventing memory leak, you can use smart pointers (shared_ptr,unique_ptr) in C++11.You can search using these terms.